# SNI not working? multiple ssl reverse proxies nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to configure two reverse proxies with ssl that proxy pass to different applications

```
https://api.example.com --> http://app:8080
https://pg.example.com --> http://pgadmin:80
```

Given the following nginx configuration, both sub-domains redirect to the first 443-server config (`app`). The problem occurs when hitting the 443 port. The redirect from 80 to 433 works fine for both. But when I browse `https://pg.example.com` it passes to `app` instead of `pgadmin`.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name api.example.com pg.example.com;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name api.example.com;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://app:8080;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name pg.example.com;

        server_tokens off;

        # note that api.example.com certificate has pg.example.com as alias
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80;
                proxy_redirect off;

                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }
}
```

Feels like the SNI is not working or so..?! But it is enabled in nginx:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.17.10
built by gcc 9.2.0 (Alpine 9.2.0) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020)
TLS SNI support enabled
```

What am I missing to make both reverse proxies work?

Edit:
When I remove the `server` block for `server_name api.example.com;` (on 443) then the other (`pg.example.com:443`) does work as expected. The `api.example.com:443` then shows the same `pgadmin` upstream).

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` blocks appear with the correct `server_name`.

Comment: It is the only included conf, but I checked it anyway and they occur as defined in the shown config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason is a misspelled domain for the `sever_name` of the
`pg.example.com:433`. Hence, not `sever_name` would match and nginx would then use the best match - which is the `api.example.com:433`.

I found out by adding a default (by making them the first in the conf file and both using `sever_name _`) server config for both 80 and 443 so I could ensure that the specific server configs are only used if the `server_name` matches. The result was that `api.example.com:433` showed the same behavior as before (indicating that it works) while the `pg.example.com:433` would show the newly configured default server - so it must be something that prevents the proper match on the server_name in the config. I triple checked the `sever_name` and finally saw the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to split up the first server block into two server-blocks.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name pg.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, but I can't guarantee, that this config is working properly with certbot.

Comment: The problem occurs when hitting the 443 port. The redirect from 80 to 433 works fine for both. But when hitting `pg.example.com:443` it passes to `app` instead of `pgadmin`.